# Extracting first coords of a GPX file

Tags: php, xml, gps, gpx

I'm trying to echo the first lat&lng coords of a GPX file but they are getting in revers order; last first... I've tried with array_reverse but I'm not being able.

Here the code:

```
<trkseg>
  <trkpt lat="43.338377" lon="-3.009481">
    <ele>11.0</ele>
    <time>2016-07-12T16:49:56Z</time>
  </trkpt>
  <trkpt lat="43.338117" lon="-3.009256">
    <ele>13.0</ele>
    <time>2016-07-12T16:50:16Z</time>
  </trkpt>
  <trkpt lat="43.338068" lon="-3.009227">
    <ele>13.0</ele>
    <time>2016-07-12T16:50:36Z</time>
  </trkpt>
  <trkpt lat="43.337982" lon="-3.009417">
    <ele>11.0</ele>
    <time>2016-07-12T16:50:56Z</time>
  </trkpt>
  <trkpt lat="43.337897" lon="-3.009664">
    <ele>8.0</ele>
    <time>2016-07-12T16:51:16Z</time>
  </trkpt>
</trkseg> 

$xml      = new SimpleXMLElement($contents);
foreach($xml->trk->trkseg->trkpt as $point){}
echo $point[lat];
echo ", ";
echo $point[lon];
```

This will echo last coords pair:`43.337897, -3.009664`

How can I echo first pair??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You're iterating to the very end with your foreach(), so it's not reversing the point order in any way,it's  just using the last point accessed, which is the end point after all that iteration

Comment: Ok @MarkBaker but what do you suggest I should do to retreive first pair of values instead of last? Thnks!!